# Changes in the datepicker widgets in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In our iOS app we have a timepicker widget to book appointments. This has worked fine for a long time. We just changed iOS developer and when he rebuilt the app the timepicker is broken for some reason we cannot tell. Has something changed recently in XCode/iOS that could explain why the layout suddenly is broken?

## How it was

[image]

## How it is now

[image]
[image: how it is now]

## This is the code responsible:

This timepicker is based on the standard iOS `UIDatePicker`.

```
class TimePickerController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var notAvailableLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fromPicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var toPicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchNotAvailable: UISwitch!
    
    var object: EventElement?
    var delegate:TimePickerControllerDelegate?
    
    var name: DEFAULT_AVAILABILITY_CONST!
    var startTime,endTime: Date?
    var isFromSettings:Bool = false
    var isNotAvailable: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = AppColors.Primary

        switchNotAvailable.setOn(isNotAvailable, animated: true)
        switchChanged(switchNotAvailable)
        
        setPickerLocale(withIdentifier: "en_GB")
        
        setPickerTimezone(withIdentifier: "UTC")
        
        initPickerDates()
        if object?.type == EVENT_CONST.lunch{
            switchNotAvailable.isHidden = true
            notAvailableLbl.isHidden = true
            
        }else{
            switchNotAvailable.isHidden = false
            notAvailableLbl.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    func setPickerLocale(withIdentifier locale: String) {
        // Changing to 24 hrs
        
        let local = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: locale) as Locale
        
        fromPicker.locale = local
        toPicker.locale = local
    }
    
    func setPickerTimezone(withIdentifier timeZone: String) {
        //set timezone
           fromPicker.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: timeZone)
           toPicker.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: timeZone)
    }
    
    func initPickerDates() {
        if let obj = object {
            let startTime = obj.start.split(separator: "Z")
            let endTime = obj.end.split(separator: "Z")
            if(startTime.first == endTime.first)
            {
                fromPicker.date = getTimeFromString(stringTime: String("08:00"))
                toPicker.date = getTimeFromString(stringTime: String("22:00"))
            }
            else{
            fromPicker.date = getTimeFromString(stringTime: String(startTime.first ?? "08:00"))
            toPicker.date = getTimeFromString(stringTime: String(endTime.first ?? "22:00"))
            }
        }else {
           if let start = startTime,let end = endTime {
            if(start == end)
            {
                // 8.00 to 22.00
                fromPicker.date = start
                toPicker.date = end.dateByAddingHours(hours: 14)
            }
            else{
              fromPicker.date = start
              toPicker.date = end
            }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func getTimeFromString(stringTime: String) -> Date
    {
        let local = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB") as Locale
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.locale = local
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringTime) ?? Date()
        print(date)
        
        return date
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnDone(_ sender: Any) {
        
        print(fromPicker.date)
        print(toPicker.date)
        
        updateEvent()
    }
    
    func updateEvent()  {

        var start = fromPicker.date.timeDisplay + "Z"
        var end = toPicker.date.timeDisplay + "Z"
        var createdDate:String = ""
        var id:String = ""
        var name:String = ""
        if object == nil {
            start = fromPicker.date.ISOISO8601StringForAvailability + "Z"
            end = toPicker.date.ISOISO8601StringForAvailability + "Z"
            createdDate = Date().toString(format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) + "Z"
            id = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
            name = self.name.rawValue
        }
        else{
            createdDate = object?.created ?? ""
            id = object?.id ?? ""
            name = (object?.name.rawValue) ?? ""
        }
        print("switch state",switchNotAvailable.isOn)
        if switchNotAvailable.isOn {
            
            if let startT = startTime,let endT = endTime {
               let startDt = "08:00Z".formatDateWithTime(referenceDate: startT)
               let endDt = "08:00Z".formatDateWithTime(referenceDate: endT)
               
                start = startDt!.toString(format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"),timezone: "UTC") + "Z"
                end = endDt!.toString(format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"),timezone: "UTC") + "Z"
            }
            else{
            
                start = "08:00Z"
                end = "08:00Z"
            }
        }
        
        ActivityIndicator().showIndicator(backgroundColor: nil)
        print("start and end date : ",start," ",end)
        let type:String?
        if isFromSettings == true{
            type = object?.type.rawValue
        }
        else{
            type = "AVAILABILITY_PATCH"
        }
        print(type ?? "AVAILABILITY_PATCH")
       
        APICalls().updateAvailability(start: start, end: end, name: name, type: type ?? "AVAILABILITY_PATCH", created: createdDate,id: id ) { (response) in
        ActivityIndicator().hideIndicator()
            if let result = response
            {
                let res = Event.init(dictionary: result as? NSDictionary ?? [:])
                DatabaseManager.getInstance().saveAvailability(object: res)
                self.delegate?.didSelectTime(from: self.fromPicker.date, to: self.toPicker.date)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What Xcode/iOS version are you using? And yes, date picker was updated in iOS 14.

Comment: iOS 14 introduced a new DateTimePicker. Try setting the [`wheels`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle/wheels) style

Answer (score 0):

To disable this time picker style, you have to add below line.

`fromPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels`

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 14 we have to define DatePickerStyle.
Please write these two lines in initPickerDates() method to set picker wheel style

```
fromPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
toPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
```

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 14, we have multiple styles for date pickers. So this is the default behavior in iOS 14.
You just need to add the following line in the initPickerDates() method.

```
fromPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
toPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
```